# $.emit is not a function on ng-select change/ngModelChange event

Tags: javascript, angular, output, onchange, eventemitter

I'm having an issue understanding what is happening in my code (Angular 13).

When I use the (change) or the (ngModelChange) of the ng-select component to call the function selectPlan(), I get this error : `ERROR TypeError: this.planSelected.emit is not a function`. Also, whatever value I put in the emit function, it does not work so I don't think the issue is coming from the value I emit.

When I call selectPlan() in every other way possible, the EventEmitter is emitting correctly (with (click) for example) and I'm receiving the Plan in the parent component. I'm using Output() and EventEmitter everywhere on my project, and it's the first time something like this happens.

Here is my component.html :

```html
<div class="dropdown-with-add-button">
    <ng-select
      class="custom-ng-select"
      notFoundText="{{ 'labelNoResultAfterResearch' | translate }}"
      id="dropdown-list-groups"
      [clearable]="false"
      [(ngModel)]="planSelected"
      (change)="selectPlan()"
    >
      <ng-container *ngIf="plansSidebar">
        <ng-option *ngFor="let plan of plansSidebar.plans">
          <div class="plan-container">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img class="plan-item-image" src="{{ plan.imageChaine }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="text-container">
              <p class="plan-item-libelle">{{ plan.libelle }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-option>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-select>
  </div>
```

And here is my component.ts :

```html
export class PlanChildComponent implements OnInit {
  _plansSidebar: PlansSidebar;
  get plansSidebar(): PlansSidebar {
    return this._plansSidebar;
  }

  @Input() set plansSidebar(value: PlansSidebar) {
    if (value) {
      this._plansSidebar = value;
      this._plansSidebar.plans.sort(
        (x, y) => x.ordreAffichage - y.ordreAffichage
      );
      if (this._plansSidebar.plans.length > 0) {
        this.selectedPlan = this._plansSidebar.plans[0];
      }
    }
  }

  @Input() idSelectedPlan: number;
  @Input() loading: boolean;

  @Output() planSelected: EventEmitter<PlanWithImage> =
    new EventEmitter<PlanWithImage>();

  selectedPlan: PlanWithImage;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  public selectPlan() {
    this.planSelected.emit(this.selectedPlan);
  }
}
```

If anyone has an idea of what's happening, thank you for letting me know !

Comment: you should not bind an output property with ngModel, `[(ngModel)]="planSelected"`, that's the problem, `planSelected` is an output prop, bind it with a normal property

Comment: I think you probably wanted to bind ngModel with `selectedPlan`

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't see this before!